# Upper Bounds Proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

The sequence $\left(s_n\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$
is defined recursively as follows: let $s_1 = 1$, and then $s_{n+1} = \sqrt{1+2s_n}$
for $n \geq 1$. (So $s_1 = 1, s_2 = \sqrt{3}, s_3 = \sqrt{1+2\sqrt{3}}$, etc.).

Use a proof by induction to prove that $3$ is an upper bound for $\left(s_n\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$.

Proof:

Base case: $n = 1$

$s_1 = 1 \leq 3$

Base case holds,

Induction Hypothesis:

Suppose that $s_{n+1} = \sqrt{1+2s_n} \leq 3$ holds for some $n$

Then for $n+1$:

$s_{n+2} = s_{n+1} + s_n$

$s_{n+2} = \sqrt{1+2s_n} + s_n$

Now I'm not sure what to do. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where did you get $s_{n+2} = s_{n+1} + s_n$ from? Your goal is to prove that $s_{n+2}\leq 3$ and you know that $s_{n+2}=\sqrt{1+2s_{n+1}}$. Try to use your induction hypothesis here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $s_{n} = \sqrt{1+2s_{n-1}} \leq 3$ holds
then we have $s_{n+1} = \sqrt{1+2s_n} \leq \sqrt{1+2*3} \leq 3$ holds
for all $n$ by induction.

Comment: you are welcome!